# Compilation error when mixing CLP(FD) and if-then-else construct

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, clpfd

I do not understand why the following code does not compile; it produces a **`put_attr/3: Uninstantiated argument expected, found 2 (1-st argument)`** error:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

test(X, Y) :-
    (   X = 1
    ->  Y #= 2
    ;   Y = 3
    ).
```

The following code also does not compile:

```
test(X, Y) :-
    (   X = 1
    ->  Y = 2
    ;   Y #= 3
    ).
```

I don't understand why that is. Replacing the `#=` with simple unification `=` makes it compile, but I don't see why this wouldn't compile considering that this predicate :

```
test(X, Y) :-
    (   X = 1
    ->  Y #= 2*_
    ;   Y = 3
    ).
```

**does compile!**

Comment: Smaller example: `t(Y) :- ( Y #= 2 ; Y = 1 ).`

Comment: @Fatalize, What do you mean it does not compile , I tried all of them and worked fine....

Comment: @coder I mean that when I `make.`, I get the error I have written in my post. Judging from @false's comment, I assume he has the exact same problem.

Comment: All of the examples work for me when I put them in a 'test.pl' file and consult it, using `make` to reload it after editing it in a way that does not change anything does not throw any errors. I can't replicate this.

Comment: @vmg I wasn't able to replicate it on another machine as well. I would like confirmation from false that he has the same error, since he posted a smaller example I assume he does.

Comment: 7.3.26-2-gfa5f4af called with `-f none` at the toplevel: `use_module(library(clpfd))`, and then `[user]. t(Y) :- ( Y #= 2 ; Y = 1 ). end_of_file.` gives above error.

Comment: BTW, what do you get for `time(use_module(library(clpfd)))`?

Comment: @false `% 908,968 inferences, 0.125 CPU in 0.136 seconds (92% CPU, 7271744 Lips) true.`

Comment: Me: `% 12,261,826 inferences, 11.566 CPU in 11.602 seconds (100% CPU, 1060204 Lips)`. Its a very old lab-top, but the number of inferences irritates me...

Comment: Just to let you know: I could also reproduce your problem, as well as the example by @false in the first comment. You should maybe report this directly to the developer of library(clpfd) if you haven't yet.

Comment: BTW, even this gives the same error: `t(Y) :- ( Y #= 0 ; Y = 0 ).`

Comment: @Boris Thanks for your reproduction. I have opened [a new issue](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/issues/170) on the SWI-Prolog dev repository to report this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug of the goal expansion of `library(clpfd)`.

This has been fixed by Markus Triska as of [this commit](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/commit/fc38bec83d47c5b49babee5949cd5a9d7a97a2fc).